# Anti-Offensive Word command spams logs

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to make an anti-offensive word bot, but when you say the word, it spams the channel that ive set it to.

It spams the channel with the embed ive made, and dosent even send the log message - (`${message.author.tag} said an offensive word. ~~ Word : ${message.content}`)

*Code*:

````
client.on('message', message =>{
        if (message.content.includes(forbidenWords[i])) {
        
    message.channel.send({embed: {
        color: 16711680,
        author: {
          name: 'hiiiii says -',
          icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/754479647466717234/a_0e2811a46da6c10576755f41d9d970bb.gif?size=128'
        },
        title: "**The word you said was forbiden.**",
        description: "*Continued language like this will result in a **mute.***",

        footer: {
          icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/754479647466717234/a_0e2811a46da6c10576755f41d9d970bb.gif?size=128' ,
          text: "Made by PixelIGPM8!"

         
        }
        
        
      }


    });
    message.delete()


    client.channels.cache.get(`764449288985772072`).send(`${message.author.tag} said an offensive word. ~~ Word : ${message.content}`)

    break;



}```
````

Comment: could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: My question is `Why does it spam logs, when theres a break statement.`

Comment: Probably because your bot is not in a loop and there is nothing to break? You are sending the offensive word as the bot and you are not checking if the message's author is a bot. So it will repeat over and over until you add that check.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a mess so I have patched it up for you. I am assuming forbiddenWords is an string array of words you don't allow.
Also, you must check if the author is a bot or not so that it doesn't respond to itself

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (msg.author.bot) { return }
    else if (new RegExp(forbiddenWords.join("|")).test(message.content)) {
        message.channel.send({
            embed: {
                color: 16711680,
                author: {
                    name: 'hiiiii says -',
                    icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/754479647466717234/a_0e2811a46da6c10576755f41d9d970bb.gif?size=128'
                },
                title: "**The word you said was forbiden.**",
                description: "*Continued language like this will result in a **mute.***",
                footer: {
                    icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/754479647466717234/a_0e2811a46da6c10576755f41d9d970bb.gif?size=128',
                    text: "Made by PixelIGPM8!"
                }
            }
        });
        message.delete();
        client.channels.cache.get(`764449288985772072`).send(`${message.author.tag} said an offensive word. ~~ Content : ${message.content}`)
    }
});
```

I've fixed your spelling of forbidden so you may need to change the name of the variable outside of the given code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why it keeps repeating the message.

The first is that you don't check if the message comes from a bot and the second is that your bot then repeats the word that triggers the message again.

To fix this, all you need to do is put this before you check for the word.

```
if (message.author.bot) return;
```